# Python multiprocessing while/for loop from user input and show time difference

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, python-multiprocessing

EDIT2: I figured it out after getting the code to work with multiprocessing; this is not a coding problem, per se, but a logic problem.

I think that I would need to assign a limit to the number size per core/process based on user input.

For example (arbitrary numbers)

- numbers < 100,000,000 = CPU 1
- numbers > 100,000,001 < 500,000,000 = CPU 2
- etc.

I would have to break up the number in chunks to give the cpus something to multiprocess.

Old question:

I'm able to get a user input and utilize a single core/process and display the time it takes to count to the number. I'm trying to get the while/for loop to be processed concurrently, to speed up the counting to the user-supplied input using multiprocessing and I'm not getting it. I've tried a lot of different methods that I've found online but they work with iterations. Is it possible to multiprocess a while/for loop?

This code works on 1 core/process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import psutil
from datetime import timedelta

def uin_Int():
    os.system('clear') #Clear the screen before beginning
    uin = input("Enter a number, or, 'q' to quit: ")
    if uin == 'q':
        os.system('clear') #Why not?
        print("Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(2) #Arbitrary time to keep the goodbye on screen
        os.system('clear') #Keeping it clean
        sys.exit(0) #Exit the program
    try:
        nuin = int(uin) #Make sure it's an integer
        return nuin #Make this available
    except ValueError:
        print("I need an integer to continue.")
        time.sleep(1.5) #Arbitrary time to keep error message on screen
        return(uin_Int())

def whyle():
    nuin = uin_Int()
    print("Counting to " + format(nuin, ',d')) #Format output to a more readable number
    processes=os.cpu_count()
    print("Number of cores: " + str(processes))
    start = time.time() # Get the current time
    a = 0 # Declare variable before time stamp and loop
    
    with mp.Pool(processes) as pool:
        for i in range(nuin):
            a += 1
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    ending = time.time()
    endtd = timedelta(seconds=(ending - start))
    print("Completed LOOP in: " + str(endtd)[:-3] + " seconds", flush=True) #Limit to three decimal points and keep it clean

if __name__ == '__main__':
    whyle()
```

Note: I put line 30 as a test to see if it's getting the correct process count, and it does return the expected amount. Eventually, that line will be removed. I've also tried a while loop in place of the "for i in range..." (that's why I called the function 'whyle') and it didn't make much difference.

I think my issue is that I'm not using 'pool' correctly and do not have

```
pool.map
```

included, but, I'm not sure where I would need to include it. I'm also thinking that I may have to break up the one function, 'def whyle()', into more functions... but I'm not sure.

If anybody has experience in this, I would sure appreciate any and all help.

I've tried several versions of the functions including pool.map() and rewriting the code into these different functions and the best I have accomplished is getting it to work on one core/process

EDIT:

I was able to get it to use all the cores/processes; however, it's extremely slow.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
from datetime import timedelta

def uin_Int():
    os.system('clear') #Clear the screen before beginning
    uin = input("Enter a number, or, 'q' to quit: ")
    if uin == 'q':
        os.system('clear') #Why not?
        print("Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(2) #Arbitrary time to keep the goodbye on screen
        os.system('clear') #Keeping it clean
        sys.exit(0) #Exit the program
    try:
        nuin = int(uin) #Make sure it's an integer
        return nuin #Make this available
    except ValueError:
        print("I need an integer to continue.")
        time.sleep(1.5) #Arbitrary time to keep error message on screen
        return(uin_Int())

def task(i):
    a = 0
    while a <= i:
        a = a + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uin = uin_Int()
    print("Counting to " + format(uin, ',d')) #Format output to a more readable number
    start = time.time() # Get the current time
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(task, range(uin))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    ending = time.time()
    endtd = timedelta(seconds=(ending - start))
    print("Completed LOOP in: " + str(endtd)[:-3] + " seconds", flush=True) #Limit to three decimal points and keep it clean
```